# using pywinauto to open two different applications. First app opens and runs. the second app 'starts()' and 'connects()' but no windows open

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

first of all, thank you for taking the time to review my question/s. This is my first attempt to ask a question so forgive me if I leave out necessary details or am too vague.

my test scripts: python2.7
pywinauto: 0.6.8

In using pywinauto to open two third party applications from my test scripts, I've been able to successfully execute the first application, but when I attempt to open the second application the start() and connect() seem to work but the second application doesn't open it window.

First app:

```
    self.app = Application(backend="uia", allow_magic_lookup=True)
   
    if not self.app.is_process_running():
       self.app.start(self.te_exe_path)

    self.app.connect(path=self.te_exe_path)
    self.window = self.app.top_window()
```

this works fine.  I can then use:

```
    windowlist = self.app.windows() to find the window names

    control_IDs = self.window.print_control_identifiers()
```

to navigate through the application's control IDs.

When I attempt to use the same calls on the second application the start() and connect() calls seem to work fine but the second application's window doesn't display.

```
    self.sec_app = Application(backend="uia", allow_magic_lookup=True)

    if not self.sec_app.is_process_running():
        self.sec_app.start(self.sec_exe_path, timeout=15)

    self.sec_app.connect(path=self.sec_exe_path)
    self.sec_window = self.sec_app.top_window()
```

The top_window() call returns an error message something like: 'No Windows of that application found', which I guess isn't surprising since the app doesn't display it's window.

I've added a few calls after the connect():

```
  self.sec_app.window()

  returns:  <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x12C4CC70>
```

if I call:

```
  self.sec_app.active()
  returns: RuntimeError: No Windows of that application are active
```

which again is no surprise since the second app didn't open it's first window.

I can manually start both applications without issue.
Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong, or what might be wrong with the second application?

Answer (score 1):

Because `connect(path="...")` can't distinguish different processes with the same executable name. You need to connect by title or by title_re:

```
 self.sec_app.connect(title="Second Window Title", timeout=10)
```

If both titles are the same, let's try to add `found_index=0` but I'm not sure it would work (need to double check).

Another way is using class `Desktop` instead of `Application`:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Second Window Title", found_index=0).wait('visible', timeout=10)
```

P.S. Of course, `found_index` could be 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: thanks for the response.  The second app is a second executable, not a second window within the same application.

Comment: Maybe the second app is started manually with some command line arguments. You can check it in Task Manager in "Details" tab by adding column "Command line" (need to right click on any column header and choose "Select columns"). https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR62W.png